# No content in UITableView cells

Tags: xcode, uitableview, cells

I know this question may seem to be answered many times before or seem like a very basic problem, but I just can't figure out what is wrong in my code. Please bear with me, I am an Objective C newbie.

I have a tableview inside of a Viewcontroller, connected to datasource and delegates. However, in my ViewController.m file when I run

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [List count];
}
```

It doesn't seem to go through. When I run it, a get a blank tableview This is the same when I try to configure other cells with

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  return 60;
}
```

And for cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}
// Configure the cell


UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"grey.png"];
imageView.image = image;
cell.backgroundView = imageView;
[[cell textLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[[cell detailTextLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

cell.textLabel.text = [datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [datasourceauthors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

In those two snippets of code, what is the tableView? How do I connect that to the actual tableView in storyboard?

Sorry again, and thanks in advance.

Comment: when debugging do you see that these methods are actually called? Also, please include your implementation of cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: No, the tableview methods are not even touched- how do I call them?

Comment: ca you send me the code. so that i can figure out what is happening

Comment: how should I go about sending you the code? the entire project? and to where?

Comment: How do you create the table view? And did you try hardcoding some values? Or setting breakpoints on these methods to check if they are called? If they are not called then you are setting the `.delegate` and `.dataSource` property wrong on your table view.

Comment: I figured out that the arrays that I was trying to use were actually NULL. My bad.